# Call Sass's compile_file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, module, sass

I'd like to call [`compile_file`](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass.html#compile_file-class_method) from Sass in my Ruby file. When I do

```
compile_file("file.scss", options)
```

I receive the error: `undefined method 'compile_file.'` Am I missing a `require` or calling it wrong? Sass is installed and I can have it watch properly when I start it in terminal. I'd like to be able to call `compile_file` on my own when I'm not watching. Could someone give me example code on how to use Sass's `compile_file` in Ruby by passing in a filename and an object for options?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Sass, but in general you need to either use fully qualified name of the method `Sass::compile_file` or require the module into global space: `require 'sass'`

Comment: When I do Sass::compile_file I get **uninitialized constant Sass** and when I do require 'sass' I get **no such file to load -- sass**

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sass'
puts 'methods available: ' + (Sass.methods.sort - Object.methods).inspect
Sass.compile_file
```

Comment: I must not be doing something correctly for Sass, because when I run your code I don't see compile_file as a method.

Comment: What methods are available?  Run `gem list` to figure out what version of Sass you are using and make sure its not really old.  You could also look in the source code of the gem itself, which should be on your machine in your gems directory.

Answer (score 0):

Install Sass before using `require 'sass'`:

`sudo gem install sass`

Now create a file `test.rb`:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'sass'
puts Sass::compile_file('./colors.scss')
```

(do `chmod +x test.rb`)

Now with `colors.scss`:

```
$color: blue !default;
p {
color: $color;
}
```

Running `./test.rb` will output:

```
p {
  color: blue; }
```

According [the docs](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#using_sass) you should use [`Sass::Engine`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Engine.html):

> Using Sass in Ruby code is very simple. After installing the Sass gem,
>   you can use it by running require "sass" and using Sass::Engine.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'sass'
sass_engine = Sass::Engine.for_file('./colors.scss', :syntax => :scss)
output = sass_engine.render
puts output
```